# Does powerline and Vim work in Windows using Cmder shell terminal?

Tags: microsoft-windows, plugin-airline

I am using the [cmder](http://cmder.net/) under Windows 7.

I am using Vim version 7.4; I'm using the airline plugin and I installed the powerline font/patch.

I followed the instruction and also added the following to my `vimrc`:

```
if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
    let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

" unicode symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = '»'
let g:airline_left_sep = '▶'
let g:airline_right_sep = '«'
let g:airline_right_sep = '◀'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␊'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␤'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '¶'
let g:airline_symbols.branch = '⎇'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'ρ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'Þ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = '∥'
let g:airline_symbols.whitespace = 'Ξ'

" airline symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = ''
let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_symbols.branch = ''
let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = ''
```

But still the status bar shows funny characters. Does the airline for Vim even work on Windows (NOT using the cygwin) just using the cmder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [issue#225](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/225) of cmder:

> This not a specific problem of cmder, but rather of cmd in general,
>   which does not use UTF-8 by default.

So just run `chcp 65001` from cmder terminal to set unicode code page to *UTF8*.

BUT this way you should run this code every time you are going to use cmder; To automate this:

> You can just add a "@chcp 65001 >nul" at the bottom of the
>   vendor/init.bat.

This way unicode will set on cmder initiation.

Answer (score 0):

In cmder setting page `Startup -> Environment`, add the following setting:

```
set LANG=en_US.utf8
chcp utf-8
```

It should solve your problem.
[image]